# c# how change datetime formart in a texbox (dd/MM/yyyy) in microsoft edge

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, data-annotations

We have a problem with the datatime format in MS Edge. Our website is running properly in IE with the correct format (dd/MM/yyyy) in IE but if we use MS Edge the validation throws an error (is nto a valid date)

We want to maintain the textboxes, we do not want any datapicker

We have try 2 approaches:

Approach 1:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfigBPAValue.PurchaseDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control default-date-picker" })
```

Approach 2:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Quarter0Date { get; set; }

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfigBPAValue.Quarter0Date, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In both cases the application expects a (yyyy/MM/dd) format.

Have we missed anything?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the references

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")    
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
```

By

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and now is working properly